# Some syntax error is occurring in the procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am unable to figure out what is the error. This is what the log says:

Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior

Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure sp1_transfer
(custid IN int,
 fromaccount int,
 toaccount IN int,
 amount IN number,
 result out varchar2)
 as
 countto int;
 tocustid int;
 fromcustid int;
 frombal number(12,2);
 countfrom int;
DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
ROLLBACK;
BEGIN
SET result = 'DB Failure';
select count(*) INTO @countfrom from accounts where accno = fromaccount;
IF countfrom < 1 THEN
SET result = "Account Not found";
END IF;
select count(*) INTO countto from accounts where accno = toaccount;
IF countto < 1 THEN
SET result = "Account Not found";
END IF;
select customers.custid into tocustid from customers, accounts where customers.custid = accounts.custid and accounts.accno=toaccount;
select customers.custid into fromcustid from customers, accounts where customers.custid= accounts.custid and accounts.accno=fromaccount;
IF tocustid = tocustid THEN 
select balance INTO frombal from accounts where accno = fromaccount;
if frombal > amount THEN 
START TRANSACTION;
update accounts set balance = balance-amount where accno = fromaccount;
update accounts set balance = balance+amount where accno = toaccount;
insert into transactions (tdate, accno, description, amount) values (sysdate(), fromaccount, 'Transfer', -amount);
insert into transactions (tdate, accno, description, amount) values (sysdate(), toaccount, 'Deposit', amount);
SET result = 'SUCCESS';
COMMIT;
ELSE
SET result = 'NSF';
END IF;
ELSE
SET result = "Cross Transfer";
END IF;
```

Comment: sql query in sql server or mysql?

Comment: Oracle SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

It means you are trying to declare something before starting the procedure.

So your statement like below

```
DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
```

should come after BEGIN as procedure starts with BEGIN and is of the form like:

```
create or replace procedure
....
BEGIN
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is a strange mixture of PL/SQL and (I assume, judging by the `@` signs) T-SQL. You really should, first of all, learn the PL/SQL (e.g. from [the best learning resource there ever was](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm)) before your start coding anything.

Your properly written stored procedure might looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure sp1_transfer
    (custid IN int,
    fromaccount int,
    toaccount IN int,
    amount IN number,
    result out varchar2)
as
    countto int;
    tocustid int;
    fromcustid int;
    frombal number(12,2);
    countfrom int;
BEGIN
    result := 'DB Failure';

    select count(*) INTO countfrom from accounts where accno = fromaccount;

    IF countfrom < 1 THEN
        result := 'Account Not found';
    END IF;

    select count(*) INTO countto from accounts where accno = toaccount;

    IF countto < 1 THEN
        result := 'Account Not found';
    END IF;

    select customers.custid into tocustid from customers, accounts where customers.custid = accounts.custid and accounts.accno=toaccount;
    select customers.custid into fromcustid from customers, accounts where customers.custid= accounts.custid and accounts.accno=fromaccount;

    IF tocustid = tocustid THEN 
        select balance INTO frombal from accounts where accno = fromaccount;
        if frombal > amount THEN 
            update accounts set balance = balance-amount where accno = fromaccount;
            update accounts set balance = balance+amount where accno = toaccount;
            insert into transactions (tdate, accno, description, amount) values (sysdate(), fromaccount, 'Transfer', -amount);
            insert into transactions (tdate, accno, description, amount) values (sysdate(), toaccount, 'Deposit', amount);
            result := 'SUCCESS';
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            result := 'NSF';
        END IF;
    ELSE
        result := 'Cross Transfer';
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLABCK;
END;
/
```

... and even then, if I was your development lead, I'd fire you in an instant for doing commits and `select count(*) ...`-s and for not re-raising/not logging exceptions. But that's already a whole different story.